# Rails rake task with update_attribute results in Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm experiencing an error I can't seem to figure out when trying to update a field in my database. I'm using rails with update_attribute via rake task. What is strange is that the error relates to a column that is not used in the task or any of the methods.

I've tried using `update_attributes` as well as `position.save(validate: false)` but they all result in the same error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

The error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'NaN' in 'field list': UPDATE `positions` SET `is_open` = 0, `cost_per_share` = NaN WHERE `positions`.`id` = 617
```

The line the error is traced to:

```
position.update_attribute(:is_open, open)
```

The task source code:

```
namespace :tom do
  desc "Update positions.is_open field"
  task check_if_open: :environment do

    include TomDate

    positions = Position.all
    positions.each do |position|

      if position.orange_highlight == 1
        open = 0
      elsif position.buy_misc == 'EXP' || position.buy_misc == 'ASSIGN' || position.sell_misc == 'EXP' || position.sell_misc == 'ASSIGN'
        if position.profit == 0 && position.loss == 0
          open = 1
        elsif position.profit > 0
          open = 0
        elsif position.loss < 0
          open = 0
        else
          open = 1
        end
      elsif tom_is_date_valid(position.buy_date) || tom_is_date_valid(position.sell_date)
        if position.profit == 0 && position.loss == 0
          open = 1
        elsif position.profit > 0
          open = 0
        elsif position.loss < 0
          open = 0
        else
          open = 1
        end
      else
        open = 1
      end

      position.update_attribute(:is_open, open)

    end

  end
end
```

Comment: You can reduce that whole error-prone mess to about 3 lines of code. This is in desperate need of refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run the update successfully after changing the `update_attribute` line to:

```
sql = "UPDATE positions SET is_open = #{open} WHERE id = #{position.id}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

I'm not sure why the update_attribute fails.